# LibreOffice 5 on Freya: Title bar and/or menu bar is missing

Tags: release-freya, applications, user-interface

I am not sure if it is a bug with elementary OS or with the new LibreOffice 5, but the LibreOffice GUI is broken. See the screenshot, where title bar is missing on unmaximised application window.

[image: Libre Office 5 GUI is broken in elementary OS Freya]

In case of maximized LibreOffice window, the menu-bar disappears. Also all dialog boxes are similarly broken. I do not currently have the maximized screenshot.

Is there any fix for menu and/or title bar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uninstall the package `libreoffice-gtk3` and install `libreoffice-gtk` instead.

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk3
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

LibreOffice should be usable again.

Comment: Strange thing happened. I uninstalled LO 4.X and installed 5.0.0.5. And it simply works. But I checked now, and libreoffice-gtk3 is not present while libreoffice-gtk is. So probably your answer is correct, although I cannot confirm that.

Comment: Rafael, if you understand the question, could you edit it to make the title more explicit, and the body more descriptive?

Comment: @waldyrious I seems like bigbang already did it :)